# GoogleTV publishing web applications

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-tv, smart-tv

I think for the web application (HTML/CSS/Js) to be published on Google Play for Google TV 2.0 platform the only way is to use the Java WebView  wrapper (or more mature solutions like PhoneGap) – is that correct?

Are there any other ways to publish directly the web applications or are any plans like those known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no current way for a web app to be published to Google Play.  YOu can wrap your app in a webView like PhoneGap does, or you can create a simple launcher that opens Chrome.  Both of those are unlikely to be featured, however.

Comment: Thanks - no plans to change it?